# Prerequisite for the book An Invitation to Modern Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Has anyone here skimmed through *An Invitation to Modern Number Theory* by Miller and Takloo-Bighash?

http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8220.html#reviews

What are some prerequisites for reading this book? Do I need to know a little about number theory ahead of reading?

(Personally, I have studied undergraduate analysis and linear algebra.)

Comment: I see. First, borrow or buy Hardy and Wright, the title is something along the lines of An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers. It covers the background, also does some of the analytic arguments, which are a strong point of the current book. I would also recommend a semester of abstract algebra, as in groups, rings, fields. The examples of these that are used in basic number theory are fairly transparent, but not if you have no idea what the definition of a group might be.

Comment: @Ruby: At the link you provided, they offer free downloads of a few selected chapters, including chapter 1. Based on a quick look, I definitely think you need some basic elementary number theory and a little group theory (through cosets and Langrange's Theorem) as prerquisite knowledge. But why not just download and skim chapter 1 to see if you fit the target audience for the book?